# How to use regular expression extractor using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter and need to simulate a scenario of about 200 users logging into the application.

using the recording controller I have recorded the steps
Note: I have replaced the actual website name with myapplication.com

Step 1 (GET): navigates to `https://myapplication.com/login`

Step 2(GET): There is an auto-redirect to

```
auth.org.domain.com/idp/saml2/idp/SSOService.php
```

Step 3 (POST): There is an auto-redirect to

```
auth.org.domain.com//idp/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php?AuthState=xxxx
```

Now the response data in Step 2 provides me with the AuthState token in following format in the body of the response

```
You were redirected to: <a id="redirlink" href="https://org.domain.com/idp/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php?AuthState=_b68bdd977f7cf900eb1b4512b56bc2d0b13dc734e2%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fauth.org.domain.com%2Fidp%2Fsaml2%2Fidp%2FSSOService.php%3Fspentityid%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Forg.domain.com%26cookieTime%3D1481072747">https://org.domain.com/idp/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php?AuthState=_b68bdd977f7cf900eb1b4512b56bc2d0b13dc734e2%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fauth.org.domain.com%2Fidp%2Fsaml2%2Fidp%2FSSOService.php%3Fspentityid%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Forg.domain.com%26cookieTime%3D1481072747
```

I can see that Auth state is repeated twice. How do I extrate the auth state here which is

```
"_b68bdd977f7cf900eb1b4512b56bc2d0b13dc734e2%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fauth.org.domain.com%2Fidp%2Fsaml2%2Fidp%2FSSOService.php%3Fspentityid%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Forg.domain.com%26cookieTime%3D1481072747"
```

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regular expression configuration:

- Apply to: `Main sample and sub-samples`
- Field to check: `Body`
- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `authstate`
- Regular Expression: `AuthState=(.+?)"`
- Template: `$1$`

Refer the extracted value as `${authstate}` where required like

```
/idp/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php?AuthState=${authstate}
```

Demo:

[image: Regular Expression JMeter SAML]

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Jakarta ORO Regular Expressions Pattern Matching Characters](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/scrapbook/jakarta-oro-2.0.6/docs/api/org/apache/oro/text/regex/package-summary.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)